# Angular Bootstrap Accordion Issue ui.bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, ui.bootstrap

I'm new to building in `angularJS` and I'm trying to implement a `ui.boostrap.accordion` as per the documentation found here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

However every time I start up my application It crashes. The whole browser freezes so I can't even view the web console to check any errors. The block of code that is causing the issue is below:

```
<uib-accordion>
      <uib-accordion-group is-open="status.open">
             <uib-accordion-heading>
                  Accordion Section Header
                  <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
               </uib-accordion-heading>
           Put content in here
      </uib-accordion-group>
 </uib-accordion>
```

When I remove this block of code the application works fine. Does anyone know where I may be going wrong? I've ensured I'm loading the `ui.boostrap` library when my application loads and I have used various other components such as `ui-btn-radio`

I'd appreciate any help.

many thanks.

Comment: I don't see any problem in the code you provided. Can you reproduce this behaviour in a snippet?

Comment: can you add a fiddle or plnkr